# Ubuntu preseed file installation hanging

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I am trying to make a [Ubuntu 11.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_11.10_.28Oneiric_Ocelot.29) (Oneiric Ocelot) installation with a preseed file using the alternate [CD-ROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CD-ROM) image. The file is as follows:

```
# Preseeding only locale sets language, country and locale.
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US
# Enable extras.ubuntu.com.
d-i    apt-setup/extras    boolean true
# Install the Ubuntu desktop.
tasksel    tasksel/first    multiselect ubuntu-desktop
# Keyboard selection.
# Disable automatic (interactive) keymap detection.
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i keyboard-configuration/layoutcode string br
# Controls whether or not the hardware clock is set to UTC.
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true
# You may set this to any valid setting for $TZ; see the contents of
# /usr/share/zoneinfo/ for valid values.
d-i time/zone string America/Sao_Paulo
### Account setup
d-i passwd/root-login boolean true
d-i passwd/make-user boolean false
### create a password with `printf "r00tme" | mkpasswd -s -m md5`
d-i passwd/root-password-crypted password $1$ZgNbzcXq$hUR0CnHVtYAvNNNnA2.br1
### Partitioning
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
d-i partman-auto/method string regular
d-i partman-auto/purge_lvm_from_device boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
  boot-root ::                                            \
          40 50 100 ext4                                  \
                  $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
                  method{ format } format{ }              \
                  use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                  mountpoint{ /boot }                     \
          .                                               \
          500 10000 1000000000 ext4                       \
                  method{ format } format{ }              \
                  use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                  mountpoint{ / }                         \
          .                                               \
          64 512 300% linux-swap                          \
                  method{ swap } format{ }                \
          .

d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

The installation goes fine until the point of the packages installation, but then it hangs. Am I missing something in the preseeding file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured that my problem was that my root partition was too small. I just increased it and everything worked.